# jQuery replaceWith if ID clicked

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a very basic website that displays streams from IP video cameras. All 5 feeds are displayed via a table which is below the '#main' feed that is inside a div. I want it so that when one of the feeds in the table is clicked, the '#main' feed will be replaced with that feed so it's displayed larger.

My JS file was just testing with the first two cam feeds.

Apologies if this isn't formatted correct, it's my first post here.

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>DSAC Cattle Feed</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='camjq.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <p>Cam 1</p>
            <img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center">Cam 1</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center">Cam 2</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center">Cam 3</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center">Cam 4</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p style="text-align:center">Cam 5</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cam1">
                        <img width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cam2">
                        <img width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="cam3" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="cam4" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img id="cam5" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//cam1
    jQuery('#cam1').click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });
    if (jQuery('#cam1').data('clicked')) 
        { $("#main").replaceWith('<p> Cam 1 </p><img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />');
        }
//cam2
    $('#cam2').click(function(){
        $(this).data('clicked', true);
    });
    if ($('#cam2').data('clicked')) 
        { $("#main").replaceWith('<p> Cam 2 </p><img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />');
        }
});
```

Comment: Whats the use of `if` in document-ready handler block

Comment: You should probably read up on how event handlers work, and do the replacing inside the event handler.

Comment: Why are the images for cam1 and cam2 surrounded by divs and the others aren't? and why do those divs have IDs instead of their child images having IDs like the others?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `replaceWith()` use `.html()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //cam1
    $('#cam1').click(function () {
        $("#main").html('<p> Cam 1 </p><img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />');
    });
    //cam2
    $('#cam2').click(function () {
        $("#main").html('<p> Cam 2 </p><img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />');
    });
});
```

Additionally, You don't need to use `.data()`

Answer (score 0):

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EjOJuso/1/edit)

```
$(function($){

  var videos = [
    "video.cgi",
    "video_bla.cgi",
    "video_something.cgi",
    "video_ola.cgi",
    "video5.cgi"
  ];

  $('[id^=cam]').click(function(){
     var n = this.id.match(/\d/g) - 1; // id number - 1 (0 based videos array);
     $("#main").html('<p> Cam '+ n +' </p><img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/'+ videos[n] +'"alt="real-time video feed" />');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the table for your video sources the same, you can use this:

```
$('td img').click(function () {
    $('#main p').html(this.id);
    $('#main img').prop('src', this.src);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4waYL/)**

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <p>Cam 1</p>
    <img width="640px" height="360px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center">Cam 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center">Cam 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center">Cam 3</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center">Cam 4</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p style="text-align:center">Cam 5</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img id="cam1" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="cam2" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="cam3" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="cam4" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img id="cam5" width="128px" height="72px" src="http://IP/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi" alt="real-time video feed" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```